# "(#tabs).tabs is not a function" - What's wrong with jquery installation with rails 3.1.3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The error (in application.js) is shown in firebug when loading the login page with localhost:3000 and the page hangs. The Gemfile looks like:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~>1.0.19'
```

The code (including the require) causing error above in application.js file is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

The purpose of the code is to load the user menu tab and is a copy from another working app.

In applicaion.html.erb, we have the following:

```
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
   <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Any thoughts about the error? Thanks so much.

UPDATE:

html source code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/assets/user_menus.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="qdYThMHV8HB+Joc9HnE3ZiR/S0hkIeulOuMsIt3iFiw=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>

<body id="login">



<h1>Login</h1>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/session" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="qdYThMHV8HB+Joc9HnE3ZiR/S0hkIeulOuMsIt3iFiw=" /></div>

<div>
    <p><label for="email">Name：</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="password">Password：</label> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" /></p>
    <p><label></label><input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="login" /></p>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: View the HTML source and include it in the question.

Comment: Can you include the generated source (ie what clicking 'view source' gives you) from your page? Make sure all the necessary JS is in fact being included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `//= require jquery-ui` to your `application.js` file if you want to use the jQuery UI functionality.

See [the project's README](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)

Comment: If add jquery_ui, there is an error:  couldn't find file 'jquery_ui'
  (in D:/rails_proj/byop/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:9). Line 9 is the //= require jquery_ui.

Comment: @user938363: `jquery-ui` != `jquery_ui`

Answer (score 1):

user938363,

Is the code above the entire html that you have? If not, could you paste the generated code please, it would really help.

Anyway, at first glance, I don't see where the `<div id='tabs'>` is located?? By adding this element, you may progress further (unless of course `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` populates the div with the appropriate div/id.

Comment: <div id='tabs'> is in a partial form in user_menus view.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this by saying I've not used Ruby.

However, that message is consistent with trying to use jquery when the jquery.js has not been loaded.

Use your browser's view source to see what `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` actually expands to. If necessary, add html comments to delineate what is produced by that line of code.

```
<!-- before -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<!-- after -->
```